# Help on testing with Selenium

Tags: javascript, testing, selenium

I'm trying to make some tests on a JavaScript application and someone advised me to use Selenium. I visited its site but I cannot understand what is it and how can I use it for testing. Can someone help me understand?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a lot of options and it can be quite daunting to start.

1. Start with the [IDE](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/). It is a Firefox plug-in and would get you writing tests in no time. This is good for semi-automated tests running only on Firefox. And good to get some scripts generated for you to kick-start your tests.
2. Setup [RC](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/remote-control/). It is a Java program that runs on 'a' box (could be localhost) spawning browsers and running your tests and you can connect to it using variety of languages and program your tests. RC is your friend if you want to automate your testing completely.
3. As for [Grid](http://selenium-grid.seleniumhq.org/), it is yet another Java program that manages different RCs on your network which makes it all distributed from browser, load and functionality perspectives. You don't need this initially and when the time comes your work on RC would be reusable 80-100%.

Comment: Thank you Maxwell this is what i was trying to understand.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the [Firefox plugin](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/), all you have to do is record a "test". Then generate the testing code in the language you want to run the scripts in. They have an option for Java - and the test can be run standalone (outside of a browser on any platform). The test will attempt to replicate what you did in the browser. If it is able to complete the same steps, your test passes.

Selenium replicates what the browser does when running it's tests and does an admirable job (though not perfect)